# Sum values of same Id in a Json Array using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json array with Id and age as follows

```
var arrayVal = [{id:"1", age: 20},{id:"2", age: 30},{id:"2", age: "20"},{id:"3", age: 20},{id:"5", age: 10}];
```

I want to get sum of age which belong to same id which will be as follows

```
1 = 20
2 = 50
3 = 20
5 = 10
```

Please find the below code

```
$scope.TestFunc = function()
{
var tot = 0;
var arrayVal = [{id:"1", age: 20},{id:"2", age: 30},{id:"2", age: "20"},{id:"3", age: 20},{id:"5", age: 10}];
for(var i=0; i <arrayVal.length; i++ )
{
  for(var j=1; j<arrayVal.length - i; j++ )
  {
    if(arrayVal[i].id == arrayVal[j].id)
    {
      tot = arrayVal[i].age.valueOf() + arrayVal[j].age.valueOf();
    }
    else{
      tot = tot + arrayVal[i].age;
    }
  }
}
console.log("-----total----"+tot);
}
```

I don't receive the expected output. the console shows the output as 202020. What has gone wrong in the above code?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Please don't invalidate your question after it has been answered by fixing the code in the question.

Answer (score 8):

With a simple [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation:

```js
const array = [{id:"1", age: 20},{id:"2", age: 30},{id:"2", age: "20"},{id:"3", age: 20},{id:"5", age: 10}];

const ages = array.reduce((a, {id, age}) => (a[id] = (a[id] || 0) + +age, a), {});

console.log(ages);
```

---

Besides the `reduce` solution being more compact and declarative, the main problem with the code provided is due to *coercion*. One of the `age` values has the string `"20"`, forcing the subsequent `+` operations to be interpreted as string concatenation.

This answer avoids this unexpected side-effect using the `+age`, forcing `age` to be a `Number` (this could be made explicit by doing `Number(age)` instead).

Comment: var arrayVal = [{id:"1", sAge: 20, eAge:30},{id:"2", sAge: 30, eAge:50},{id:"2", sAge: 20, eAge:40},{id:"3", Aage: 20, eAge:50},{id:"5", sAge: 10, eAge:30}]; If I have an array like this how can get the diff between each sAge and eAge of each id and sum them seperately?

Comment: That should be asked as a new question, but the same principles apply.

Answer (score 0):

The age must be number. It should not be as a string. In your code, id:2 has 20 as string. Kindly check with datatype in arrayVal.

var arrayVal = [{id:"1", age: 20},{id:"2", age: 30},{id:"2", age: 20},{id:"3", age: 20},{id:"5", age: 10}];

```
$scope.TestFunc = function()
{
var tot = 0;
var arrayVal = [{id:"1", age: 20},{id:"2", age: 30},{id:"2", age: 20},{id:"3", age: 20},{id:"5", age: 10}];
for(var i=0; i <arrayVal.length; i++ )
{
  for(var j=1; j<arrayVal.length - i; j++ )
  {
    if(arrayVal[i].id == arrayVal[j].id)
    {
      tot = arrayVal[i].age.valueOf() + arrayVal[j].age.valueOf();
    }
    else{
      tot = tot + arrayVal[i].age;
    }
  }
}
console.log("-----total----"+tot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared another answer using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method which returns array of objects instead of simple array:

```js
const arrayVal = [{id:"1", age: 20},{id:"2", age: 30},{id:"2", age: "20"},{id:"3", age: 20},{id:"5", age: 10}];

let summedAges = arrayVal.reduce((a, c) => {
 let filtered = a.filter(el => el.id === c.id);
 if(filtered.length > 0){
  a[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].age += +c.age;
 }else{
  a.push(c);
 }
 return a;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(summedAges));
```