# Sum values of same Id in a JSON Array using angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sum

I have an json array as follows

```
var arrayVal = [{id:"1", sAge: 20, eAge:30},{id:"2", sAge: 30, eAge:50},{id:"2", sAge: 20, eAge:40},{id:"3", Aage: 20, eAge:50},{id:"5", sAge: 10, eAge:30}];
```

I want to take difference of sAge and eAge of each id and sum the final value if there are multiple diff values of same id. Output should be as follows

```
1 = 10,
2 = 40,
3 = 30,
5 = 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost identical to your (?) [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536047/sum-values-of-same-id-in-a-json-array-using-js/56536071):

```js
var array = [{id:"1", sAge: 20, eAge:30},{id:"2",sAge:30, eAge:50},{id:"2",sAge:20,eAge:40},{id:"3",sAge:20,eAge:50},{id:"5",sAge:10,eAge:30}];

const ages = array.reduce((a, {id, sAge, eAge}) => (a[id] = (a[id] || 0) + eAge - sAge, a), {});

console.log(ages);
```

<sub>Note: also fixed the typos in your object.</sub>

Comment: If I want to pass the name of the person as an element to ages variable how can I do that?